# Adding a drop down in a table using HTML

Tags: html

Anyone can help me, I really can't hide content in HTML?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    #section1 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    #LinkBar {
      width: 100%;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
    }
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      background-color: red;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .menubar {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    #logo {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }
    span:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    #dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #FF0000;
      min-width: 160px;
      padding: 12px 16px;
    }
    #dropdown:hover,
    #dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <link href="menubar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <section id="section1">
    <img src="logo.png" id="logo" alt="LOGO" height="243" width="480" />


    <h1>
<table id="LinkBar">
<tr>
<td><a href="homepage.html" class="menubar">Home</a></td>
<td><a href="menu.html" class="menubar">Menu</a></td>
<td><a href="delivery.html" class="menubar">Delivery</a></td>
<td><a href="promotion.html" class="menubar">Promotion</a></td>

<td>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <span class="menubar">About Us</span>
        <div id="dropdown-content">
          <a href="Our History.html" class="menubar">Our History</a>
          <a href="Our History.html" class="menubar">Nutritional</a>
          <a href="Our History.html" class="menubar">Achievement</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
    
<td><a href="storefinder.html" class="menubar">Store Finder</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</h1>
  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

I am a beginner of HTML. I tried a lot of time and tried to find the problem out. But it doesn't work, I really hope that anyone can help me to solve it (T.T)

Comment: You'd really be better off not using a table for layout. Here is a question with a [simple dropdown menu using list items and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687057/simple-dropdown-menu). You'd need to do some styling to make the list item come straight down instead of being indented but it is doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for dropdown:

```
    <div id="dropdown">

    <ul style="list-style-type:none"><li><span class="menubar">About Us</span>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="Our History.html" class="menubar">Our History</a></li>
    <li><a href="Our History.html" class="menubar">Nutritional</a></li>
    <li><a href="Our History.html" class="menubar">Achievement</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>    
   </div>
```

also add css below in style tag for ul and li elements:

```
ul li {
position: relative;
}

ul ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
}

ul > li:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-color: #FF0000;
}
```